# What mnemonics help solve common linguistic issues?

Tags: grammar, orthography

Example: i before e, except after c.

Are there mnemonic devices to help remember other spelling and grammar issues? Bonus points for pointing out exceptions to the rule.

Comment: "... or when sounded like "a", as in *neighbor* or *weigh*."

Comment: E before i, not after c, not sounding like "a": foreign, albeit, theist. I before e, after c: ancient, science, efficient.

Comment: I think that's not what most linguists would consider a "linguistic issue", as it's just about spelling.

Comment: Well, the *answers* so far do focus on spelling, but the question itself is about "spelling *and grammar* issues". It is also tagged as "spelling" and "grammar", so I can see where the word "linguistic" in the title comes from.

Comment: The best clarification of “i before e” I know is: “When it sounds like ‘e e’, put ‘i’ before ‘e’, except after ‘c’.”  The only common exception I know to this is “seize”.

Answer (score 4):

Another spelling one:

> necessary = never eat chips; eat salmon sandwiches and remain young.

Answer (score 3):

To continue with the spelling theme, there is A RAT in 'separate'. This has helped me at times.  I wish someone would come up with one for 'definitely'.

Comment: Well, for certain parts of our audience, a simple "there is 'fini' in 'definite'" might work. For the rest of us, how about memorizing "definitely finished" or some such? It's even backed up by etymology (as opposed to that "rat" in "separate"), because both "definitely" and "finish" ultimately come from Latin *finis* ("boundary, limit, border, end").

Comment: Also useful: there's a rat in the laboratory.

Comment: "They buried Terry in the cemetery", and "The nuns drilled us in pronunciation"...

Answer (score 2):

I've become rather fond of the expression "*an hour and a half*"; it's a quick way to remember which of the two articles "a" or "an" should I use in a situation.

Answer (score 1):

Week vs weak.
As they say, unity is strength. Hence, two 'e's united can not be lacking in strength.

Answer (score 1):

We were taught the following mnemonics for remembering which prepositions are followed by which cases in German:

- I HAZ A NU VÜ: accusative or dative (in, hinter, an, etc)
- BO FUDGE: accusative (bis, ohne, für, etc)
- MAZ BEG SNAV: dative (mit, aus, zu, etc)

That last one doesn't make much sense, but I can still remember it after nearly 20 years, so it must have worked!

Comment: When I took German, I'd sing "aus ausser bei mit, nach seit, von zu" to the Blue Danube tune, and "an auf hinter in vor neben ueber unter zwischen" to the Ode to Joy. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Some occasionally memorable spelling aids here: [your dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/library/misspelled.html)